# my first WCF server - works with "string" but doesn't work with custom interface?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've implemented my first WCF application.
I need one method `IConsoleData GetData();`
I receive `CommunicationException "There was an error reading from the pipe: The channel was closed. (109, 0x6d)."` in client.

When I replaced `IConsoleData GetData();` to `string GetData();` application become functionable.

How should I fix the code to use `IConsoleData GetData()`?

Server:

```
//public interface IConsoleData
//{
//    double GetCurrentIndicator();
//}

//public class IConsoleDataImpl : IConsoleData
//{
//    public double GetCurrentIndicator()
//    {
//        return 22;
//    }
//}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    //IConsoleData GetData();
    string GetData();
}

public class MBClientConsole : IMBClientConsole
{
    //public IConsoleData GetData()
    //{
    //    return new IConsoleDataImpl();
    //}
    public string GetData()
    {
        //return new IConsoleDataImpl();
        return "hello";
    }
}

class Log
{

    private ServiceHost _host;

    public void initialize()
    {
        _host = new ServiceHost(typeof (MBClientConsole),
                                new Uri[]
                                    {
                                        new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
                                    });
            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMBClientConsole),
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "PipeReverse");

            _host.Open();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);
            // TODO: host.Close();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
//public interface IConsoleData
//{
//    double GetCurrentIndicator();
//}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    //IConsoleData GetData();
    string GetData();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IMBClientConsole> pipeFactory =
            new ChannelFactory<IMBClientConsole>(
                new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(
                    "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

        IMBClientConsole pipeProxy =
          pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        while (true)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("pipe: " +
              //pipeProxy.GetData().GetCurrentIndicator());
              pipeProxy.GetData());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error you are reporting seems to be much more related to channel availability rather than a DataContract issue. How would it work if you make GetData to return an object of tyoe: IConsoleDataImpl Ah, P.S. remove the first I and just call it ConsoleData if is a class ;-)

Comment: yeap sorry for confusions, actually I rarely use 'I' cause i'm programming on Java mostly were 'I' is not very popular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use an Interface you have to do two things:

1. the implementations needs to be serializable (use the DataContract - Attribute)
2. you have to tell the service the [*known types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) if you use the interface (here it's IConsoleDataImpl)

Make your live easier and decorate the implementation with DataContract and the members of it with DataMember Attributes and use the implementation instead of the interface.

You can find a lot about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

(and don't begin the implementations name with "I")

here is a rework without the known-type stuff and I think this will help you for your
first steps - no need to dig in that deep (Interfaces + KnownTypes) yet.

```
[DataContract]
public class ConsoleData
{
    [DataMember]
    public double CurrentIndicator
    {
        get { return 22; }
        set { /* whatever */ }
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    ConsoleData GetData();
}
```

Comment: Now I receive "Cannot resolve symbol 'DataContract'". I'm trying to google the solution but if you know it it would be appreciated.

Comment: ok i've aded System.Runtime.Serializations to references. Now I receive "Attribute 'DataMember' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations."

Comment: DataMember is for properties and fields and such - you made a function so you need the OperationContract - just like you did in your own solution

Comment: thanks, it works. I've also changed DataContract in your code to ServiceContract

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems there.  First, your interface should be marked as a [DataContract]

```
[DataContract]
public interface IConsoleData
{
    double GetCurrentIndicator();
}
```

Now, when WCF sends an IConsoleData over the wire, it is going to serialize the data in the class, send it, and deserialize it on the client.  The problem with your implementation is that it contains nothing that can be serialized.

```
public class IConsoleDataImpl : IConsoleData
{
    public double GetCurrentIndicator()
    {
        return 22;
    }
}
```

If you were to build a client using `svcutil.exe` from the above, it would create the IConsoleDataImpl class, but the `GetCurrentIndicator` method wouldn't do anything. Important distinction here: WCF will transmit DATA, not IMPLEMENTATION.

What you *probably* want here is something more like:

```
[DataContract]
public interface IConsoleData
{
    [DataMember]
    double CurrentIndicator { get; set; }
}

public class ConsoleDataImpl : IConsoleData
{
    public double CurrentIndicator { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ConsoleDataImpl))]
public interface IMBClientConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    IConsoleData GetData();
}

public class MBClientConsole : IMBClientConsole
{
    public IConsoleData GetData()
    {
        return new IConsoleDataImpl() { CurrentIndicator = 22 };
    }
}
```

Although at this point the `IConsoleData` interface isn't really needed, and I would just remove it.

But basically the thing to remember is in general, you want your WCF services to contain methods, and your data contracts to contain properties (or fields). The implementation inside a method in a DataContract will not be in the client if you generate a client from he WSDL, that would only work if you were to copy over a shared dll with the DataContracts to the client.

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: thanks, complicated things :) i've implemented as suggested in the comment above. now I avoid interfaces and DataContract keyword. works so far..